# WARNING: expo-cli has not yet been tested against Node.js v16.3.0

Tags: react-native, expo

Installed the latest version of NodeJS and this warning is coming up after installing expo-cli.

```js
WARNING: expo-cli has not yet been tested against Node.js v16.3.0.
If you encounter any issues, please report them to https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues

expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:
* >=12.13.0 <13.0.0 (Maintenance LTS)
* >=14.0.0 <15.0.0 (Active LTS)
* >=15.0.0 <17.0.0 (Current Release)
```

How do I suppress this warning?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Git Bash? Try to use normal cmd to create the project instead.